# A precise definition needed

Tags: limits, functions

Let a function $f$ be such that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Then give a definition of

• the *$n$-th iterate $f^{(n)}$  of  $f$*

• a *limit cycle of order $k$ for $f$*

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Define recursively, $f^{(0)}=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R}$, $f^{(n+1)}=f\circ f^{(n)}$.

Comment: What are you asking for? You know the concepts and want a formal definition? Or you are not sure what the concepts mean and want them defined rigorously?